# Accessing a specific element of an Array RDD in apache-spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a RDD that is containing an array of key,value pairs. I want to get an element with key (say 4).

```
scala> val a = sc.parallelize(List("dog","tiger","lion","cat","spider","eagle"),2)
a: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:27
scala> val b = a.keyBy(_.length)
b: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at keyBy at <console>:29
```

I have tried to apply filter on it but getting error.

```
scala> val c = b.filter(p => p(0) = 4);
<console>:31: error: value update is not a member of (Int, String)
         val c = b.filter(p => p(0) = 4);
```

I want to print the key,value pair with specific key (say 4) as `Array((4,lion))`

The data is always coming in the form of an array of key,value pair

Comment: Good post , but does it answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `p._1` instead of `p(0)`.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List("dog", "tiger", "lion", "cat", "spider", "eagle"), 1)

val kvRdd: RDD[(Int, String)] = rdd.keyBy(_.length)
val filterRdd: RDD[(Int, String)] = kvRdd.filter(p => p._1 == 4)

//display rdd
println(filterRdd.collect().toList)

List((4,lion))
```

Comment: It is working. I am not able to understand the solution you did as I am new to apache spark. Can you please enlighten on this?

Comment: you can access tuple elements with `_` only. Here `kvRdd` is an `RDD` of tuples. [tuples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_tuples.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There's a [`lookup`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L937) method applicable to RDDs of Key-Value pairs (RDDs of type `RDD[(K,V)]`) that directly offers this functionality.

```
b.lookup(4)
// res4: Seq[String] = WrappedArray(lion)

b.lookup(5)
// res6: Seq[String] = WrappedArray(tiger, eagle)
```